# Como abrir uma arquivo .txt no matlab que tenha muitos elementos?

Tags: matlab

Quando a matriz possui poucos elementos o comando dlmread fuciona mas no caso de uma matriz de ordem alta não. Gostaria de ter acesso as colunas da matriz.

Comment: Forneça mais detalhes amigo, Mostre a matriz com poucos elementos e a com muitos elementos!

Comment: A matriz está em um arquivo .txt proveniente de uma simulação. Quando tento abri-la com o comando que sempre usei, dlmread('nomedoarquivo.txt'), aparece a mensagem na workspace: Too many elements. Gostaria de saber outro comando que eu possa usar para ter acesso as colunas da matriz.

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar o `tblread` ao invés do `dlmread`!

Você conseguira ler arquivos com essa estrutura:

```
Latitude » Longitude » City
42.3584  » -71.0598  » Boston
40.4167  » -3.7003   » Madrid
41.8955  » 12.4823   » Rome
```

E ainda poderá usar delimitadores para buscar as posições corretas!

[Fonte para pesquisa e entendimento do comando citado!](http://www.iit.upcomillas.es/palacios/matlab/matlab_io.html)